# Getting error: Error in UseMethod("content", x) : no applicable method for 'content' applied to an object of class "character"

Tags: r, corpus

I'm trying to run a word replace on Corpus.

Getting the following error:  Error in UseMethod("content", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'content' applied to an object of class "character"

Changed original code:

```
docs<-tm_map(
  docs, content_transformer(
    function(x) gsub(x, pattern = "bacillus subtilis", replacement = "bacillus_subtilis")
    )
  )
```

To this thinking it would eliminate the error, but no dice.

```
tobacsub <- content_transformer(function(x, pattern) {return (gsub(pattern, "bacillus_subtilis", x))})
docs<-tm_map(docs, tobacsub, "bacillus subtilis")

#create the tobacsub content transformer
tobacsub <- content_transformer(function(x, pattern) {return (gsub(pattern, "bacillus_subtilis", x))})
docs<-tm_map(docs, tobacsub, "bacillus subtilis")
```

> Error in UseMethod("content", x) :    no applicable method for
>   'content' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: Welcome to SO :) One hint for formatting your posts - your can format your code as code ( 4 times space before the code)

Comment: Thanks @stats0007, still trying to get the hang of things.